Lucene query time joins not working, return zero results
I am trying to perform a query time join of two separate indexes, with different document types, using Lucene query time join.
Each index is valid, and they share a common "ID" Long value that allows the join. However, the join query is returning ZERO results.
I must be doing something wrong, any ideas or help greatly appreciated as I have worked on this for several days.
I tried to join the two indexes using a common Long field, but it returns no results.
The following class will build two indexes (from & to) and then attempt to run a join query against them.
package org.test;

import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;

import org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Document;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Field;
import org.apache.lucene.document.FieldType;
import org.apache.lucene.document.NumericDocValuesField;
import org.apache.lucene.document.StoredField;
import org.apache.lucene.document.TextField;
import org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig;
import org.apache.lucene.index.Term;
import org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanClause;
import org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanQuery;
import org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher;
import org.apache.lucene.search.Query;
import org.apache.lucene.search.TermQuery;
import org.apache.lucene.search.TopDocs;
import org.apache.lucene.search.join.JoinUtil;
import org.apache.lucene.search.join.ScoreMode;
import org.apache.lucene.store.Directory;
import org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory;
import org.apache.lucene.store.NIOFSDirectory;

public class LuceneJoinTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            buildIndex("C:\\Temp\\index\\fromIndex", "fromFieldId", 50);
            buildIndex("C:\\Temp\\index\\toIndex", "toFieldId", 10);
            searchIndex();

        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void buildIndex(String path, String fieldName, int docCount) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("buildIndex:" + path);
        Analyzer la = new StandardAnalyzer();
        IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(la);
        config.setRAMBufferSizeMB(50);
        Directory d = new NIOFSDirectory(FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(path));
        IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(d, config);

        for (int i = 1; i <= docCount; i++) {
            System.out.println("Created Document:" + i);
            Integer id = Integer.valueOf(i);
            Document doc = new Document();

            FieldType storedOmitNorms = new FieldType(TextField.TYPE_STORED);
            storedOmitNorms.setOmitNorms(false);
            doc.add(new Field("id", id.toString(), storedOmitNorms));
            doc.add(new NumericDocValuesField(fieldName, id.longValue()));
            doc.add(new StoredField(fieldName, id.longValue()));

            FieldType fieldNotStoredOmitNorms = new FieldType(TextField.TYPE_NOT_STORED);
            fieldNotStoredOmitNorms.setOmitNorms(false);
            doc.add(new Field("content", "one two three...", fieldNotStoredOmitNorms));

            writer.addDocument(doc);
        }

        writer.close();
    }

    public static void searchIndex() throws Exception {

        Directory fromIndex = FSDirectory.open(new File("C:\\Temp\\index\\fromIndex").toPath());
        IndexReader fromReader = DirectoryReader.open(fromIndex);
        IndexSearcher fromSearcher = new IndexSearcher(fromReader);

        // Test the FROM INDEX
        BooleanQuery.Builder fromQueryBuilder = new BooleanQuery.Builder();
        Term fromTerm = new Term("content", "two");
        fromQueryBuilder.add(new TermQuery(fromTerm), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
        Query fromQuery = fromQueryBuilder.build();

        TopDocs fromResults = fromSearcher.search(fromQuery, 100);
        System.out.println("fromSearcher results:" + fromResults.totalHits);

        // Test the TO INDEX
        Directory toIndex = FSDirectory.open(new File("C:\\Temp\\index\\toIndex").toPath());
        IndexReader toReader = DirectoryReader.open(toIndex);
        IndexSearcher toSearcher = new IndexSearcher(toReader);

        BooleanQuery.Builder toQueryBuilder = new BooleanQuery.Builder();
        Term toTerm = new Term("content", "three");
        toQueryBuilder.add(new TermQuery(toTerm), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
        Query toQuery = toQueryBuilder.build();

        TopDocs toResults = toSearcher.search(toQuery, 100);
        System.out.println("toSearcher results:" + toResults.totalHits);

        // Now test with a JOIN...

        Query joinQuery = JoinUtil.createJoinQuery("fromFieldId", false, "toFieldId", Long.class, fromQuery,
                fromSearcher, ScoreMode.None);

        TopDocs joinResults = toSearcher.search(joinQuery, 100);
        System.out.println("joinResults:" + joinResults.totalHits);

    }
}

